# Adding an onclick event a list item in KnockoutJS.

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm having an issue with binding an onclick event to a ul list.  Here is my html:

```
<ul id="burgerist" data-bind="foreach: burgerList.sort(function (l, r) { return l.name() > r.name() ? 1 : -1 }), click: showmap">
                        <li data-bind=" text: name"></li>
                    </ul>
```

The problem I'm having is on the showmap function. I'm trying to return the name in an alert box:

```
var ViewModel = function() {
    var self = this;

    this.burgerList = ko.observableArray([]);

    initialBurgerJoints.forEach(function(burgerItem){
        self.burgerList.push( new BurgerJoint(burgerItem) );        
        addmarker(burgerItem.lat, burgerItem.long, burgerItem.name, burgerItem.comments);
    });

    self.showmap = function(data) {
        alert(this.name);
    };      
}
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The click binding looks good (at least it should show an alert with something in it). but the foreach binding is not right .. that is probably what is causing the click event not to work. you are binding to a sort method that is not returning an array ... if you remove the sort it should work. for your reference https://jsfiddle.net/agfejkr4/1/

Comment: I left off the array of places for brevity.  I could paste it in if you'd like to see it.

Comment: I copied your fiddle and added in the array.  I'm still having an issue, could you take a look at it.?  https://jsfiddle.net/brettdavis4/y1f1uho9/1/

Comment: I took your answer and the other posters answer and made this: https://jsfiddle.net/brettdavis4/4q1mL6dw/2/  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The click binding needs to be on each item in the list instead of on the list itself. The function will be passed the current context which in this case would be a burger in burgerList.

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: burgerList.sort(function (l, r) { return l.name() > r.name() ? 1 : -1 })">
    <li data-bind="text: name, click: $component.showmap"></li>
</ul>

this.showmap = function(burger) {
    alert(burger.name());
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!  I've got it working!  https://jsfiddle.net/brettdavis4/4q1mL6dw/2/